# How to integrate payment gateway using joomla

Tags: joomla, payment, gateway

I'm new to joomla can any one please tell me how to integrate payment gateway module using joomla.

Comment: Please visit [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/e-commerce/payment-gateway) site

Comment: another [cool site](https://techjoomla.com/documentation-for-common-payment-gatewaycpg-api-for-joomla/just-4-steps-to-integrating-payments-into-your-joomla-extensions-common-payments-api-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

To integrate payment gateway in joomla 
Please refer the below link

http://extensions.joomla.org/category/e-commerce/payment-gateway